# Tomcat7 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory

I am running tomcat7 service which process quite a big load from customers. I left application during a weekend and when I back I noticed that tomcat CPU usage increased to 99% and in the logs I have found following errors:

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-908" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-948" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Does it means that at the time I've got OutOfMemory exception I had 908 and 948 opened active threads?

Currently my tomcat is runnning under default configurations I've never increased heap size yet.

We are receiving around `200 queries/sec`.

```
My hardware:
CPU : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz
Memory: 2GB
```

Could you please point me into right direction, what should I look at in order to resolve this issue.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 2 GB seems low for a server system, I would advise to get at least 8 GB. Try setting Java parameters -Xms and -Xmx to at least 1 GB. And as always check your code to see if you're forgetting to clean up stuff.

Comment: Please move common jar file to tomcat lib folder

Comment: @Davio "2GB seems low for a server system" is a meaningless phrase. It REALLY depends on the type of server and of course load. I have servers running perfectly fine with 512Mb or less, while others require 128Gb.

Comment: Usually putting more memory without knowing why is reaching top, just mask the inner problem. I recommend you profile your memory and try to find where (and why, maybe it's just needed, not bad programmed at all) are going the server resources or why they aren't properly released after use.

Comment: If your memory is inscreasing constantly

Comment: If the application memory is increasing constantly it probably has a memory leak in some point like exoddus said. It's worth spend some time to analyse it.

Comment: Probably useless, but use JProfiler to check that there is no leak, or at least you will find which class is filling the heap.

Comment: You just said it is processing a big load.  Is it loading a flat file or reading in a large group of records all at once?  If so that does not scale.  The app needs to read in and processing the data in sections it can handle like say maybe 500 rows or records at a time.   What ever it is doing it is too big for the current configured memmory.

Comment: Have you run something like ps -ef | grep -i java to confirm that the memory parameters being set are actually being applied to the JVM.  Just because the machine has 2GB of RAM does not mean the JVM is configured to 2GB.

Comment: It totally depends on the size of your application, try taking the heapdump analyse the heap dump with several tools available in market like jvisual vm, jhat, jmap. That would help you track down the cause of the memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

When your JVM runs out of a particular resource, 
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error will occur.

**Solution 1 :** You should *increase the availability of that resource*. When your application does not have enough Java heap space memory to run properly. For that, you need to alter your JVM launch configuration and add the following:
                   `-Xmx1024m`
The above configuration would give the application 1024MB of Java heap space. You can use g or G for GB, m or M for MB, k or K for KB. For example all of the following are equivalent to saying that the maximum Java heap space is 1GB:

```
 -Xmx1073741824 
 -Xmx1048576k 
 -Xmx1024m 
 -Xmx1g
```

**Solution 2 :**  If your application contains a *memory leak*, adding more heap will just postpone the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error. 
If you wish to solve the underlying problem with the Java heap space instead of masking the symptoms, you have several tools available. 
For Example: Plumbr tool. Among other performance problems it catches all java.lang.OutOfMemoryErrors and automatically tells you what causes them. You can go through about other available tools. And the choice is yours!

**Source:**
https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space

Comment: It's not a good idea to just post a link. It may change in the future. Rather explain and use the link as backing.

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of reasons,

1. Since you have not increased the default memory allocation,  with high load,  it probably won't have enough resources to serve all requests and some are obviously running out of memory.  So first thing to try is to tweak the jvm memory configuration.
2. If 1 does not working,  it could be a bug in your application that might be preventing garbage collection. You might want to run your application with a profiler attached to see what objects are collected over time and use that information to debug.